# JavaFX Dialogs remove header decoration

Tags: javafx, dialog

Is there a quick way to remove a Dialog header in JavaFX? Or should i just go and create my own dialog?

```
TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
dialog.setTitle("create DATABASE");
dialog.setHeaderText("create DATABASE");
dialog.setContentText("Ingrese un nombre:");
dialog.showAndWait().ifPresent(name -> getCodeArea().setTemplateInjump("create database "+name+";\n\nuse "+name+";\n\n"));
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `dialog.setHeaderText(null)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by setting the graphic and header text to null:

```
dialog.setHeaderText(null);
dialog.setGraphic(null);
```

Answer (score 6):

It's very simple set `dialog.setHeaderText(null)` and it will remove the header. 
For more information have a look [here](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/)