# JavaFX dialog without icon

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, icons

I don't know how to create a dialog without any icon in JavaFX. I've tried

```
((Stage)dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow()).getIcons().clear();
```

but it still leaves the ugly default icon (on Windows 10) of dialog. Is there any better way than setting empty PNG as icon? If so give me the hint.

Comment: Dialogs don't have icons by default, as far as I can tell and at least from my testing on a Mac.  Perhaps you are using a different platform with different behavior.  It might be an idea to edit your question to add more information on your environment, include an [mcve] and show some screenshots which demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288981/javafx-dialogs-remove-header-decoration?

Answer (score 0):

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Answer (score -1):

When you want to get rid of icon you may switch window style to make only content visible without closed, minimize, etc, buttons and also without icon.

[javadoc Dialog class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#initStyle-javafx.stage.StageStyle-)

```
dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

> Specifies the style for this dialog. This must be done prior to making
>   the dialog visible. The style is one of: StageStyle.DECORATED,
>   StageStyle.UNDECORATED, StageStyle.TRANSPARENT, StageStyle.UTILITY, or
>   StageStyle.UNIFIED.

Comment: It removes the window header as well (at least on Windows 10). That is not what I need.